# Server not responding for route

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm running `ReactJS` with an `Express` backend. Running the `Express` server on `PORT=3001` and using proxy for `React` to the same PORT.

There are two routes created within my backend : `/users` and `/`. Both files are sending a `JSON` as a response.

```
//Both routes are returning a JSON (list of objects)

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json([
    { id: '1', name: 'Billy' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Bob' }
  ]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/users` the `JSON` is served to me as it should. Now when I go to the `http://localhost:3000/` route, nothing appears and I get an error saying : `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. Also, for context, my component is retrieving this information and displaying all the users.

Why is my JSON response being displayed correctly for the `/users` route and not for `/` route?

Comment: Your server is running on port 3001 but you're requesting port 3000 (which is default react dev server port) that might returns html (that's why it says unexpected token <)

Comment: If you're proxying your server to react dev server that's wrong way to do what you wanted to do. Instead you should build react app (using yarn run build I think) and use express to serve build artifacts. Using react dev server in production is not a good idea because it's for development proposes.

Answer (score 1):

I think because you handled "/" route to return `index.html` of React.

Comment: I think same too